# Tree Traversal with multiple parameters

Tags: c++, c, recursion, tree, traversal

I am trying to traverse a tree and print out its contents in prefix, postfix, and infix notation. At the moment, the program only prints out one operator of the expression entered.

I have seen methods of completing this recursively, but they have all used one parameter in their function, which was directly related to the Node's class. ([Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Implementations/))

How would I go about traversing the left and right nodes of the tree recursively with multiple parameters? Or is that even a viable option?
The code that is giving me issues are lines 32-42 in "expressiontree.cpp" but I have included the header file and an example of what the code outputs for context.

[CODE](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4391b3eb256b1299778bc2c376211241) (The link directs to GitHub because the native text editor is giving me some issues.)

Thanks for any ideas you guys have!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done recursively with more than one parameter, but you will have to pass in a pointer to an "ETreeNode" instance every time, like so:

```
bool ETreeNode::preorder(ETreeNode* currentNode, char* s, int& n, const int& len){
    bool error = false;

    if (!currentNode) // insure that the "currentNode" is not NULL
        return true; // you can change this to implement your "error" variable if you want to

    //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    if (m_bIsOperator)
    { //operator node
        s[n++] = m_chOp; //append operator character to s

        preorder(currentNode->m_pLeftChild, s, n, len); // move to the next left node
        preorder(currentNode->m_pRightChild, s, n, len); // move to the next right node 

        s[n++] = '\0'; //zero terminator
    } //if
    else
    { //number node
        char buffer[32]; //temporary character buffer
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", m_nValue); //print number into buffer
        strcat((char*)(s + n), buffer); //append buffer to s
    } //else

    return error;
} //preorder
```

**Question:** Is your data tree is in infix order?

You are going to want to implement some code to make sure that "n" never becomes equal to or greater than "len".

You will also want to implement a way to keep your program from writing a zero terminator after every iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll try this and see how it works out.

Comment: Using your method gave me compiler errors because the function is being used in another related file. As per the instructions, I cannot modify anything other than the files I have documented here. I see how your method would work, but I do not think it is viable in my specific circumstance. 

Is there a method in which the function still only takes 3 parameters?

Comment: Normally, with data structures such as these there is a class that represents and manages the data structure itself and then there is at least one other sub-class that represents elements of that data structure.  Is this the case with yours? For example, do you have class called "ETree" or something like that?  You said that you cannot modify the "ETreeNode" class because of the "instructions" that you have; does that mean that this is a school project or something like that?  Are you able to add new classes or not?  Last question, if there is a parent-class, are you able to modify that?